# How to pull out an Order prop and call api in that particular order

Tags: c#, collections

I have three lists:

```
List<Foo> foos
List<Bar> bars`
List<John> jhons
```

these 3 lists are part of root object called for example `MainObject` class

```
public class MainObject 
{
   public List<foo> Foos {get;set;}
   public List<bar> Boos {get;set;}
   public List<jhon> Jhons {get;set;}
}
```

each type of these lists have some common properties, among them property `int Order`

Now, I have a method which as input argument has MainObject object and then I need to call an api service **in that specific order** which all lists have but **for different endpoints**

Example:

```
public async Task<Guid> SaveItem(MainObject item)
{

   //this code will go ignoring the order contained in each item of each list
   if(item.Foos.Any())
     await _service.CreateItem(Constants.CreateFoos, item)
   if(item.Bars.Any())
     await _service.CreateItem(Constants.Bars, item)
   if(item.Johns.Any())
     await _service.CreateItem(Constants.CreateJohns, item)
}
```

Here, for example third item in list `List<Bars>` can be Order = 1, then first item of third list can be Order = 2, and so on.

How to call appropriete endpoint ordered by Order property?

Because all three lists have base class for example `CommonBase` class.

Maybe I can do something like:

```
var allLists = item.Foos.Cast<CommonBase>.Concat(item.Bars.Cast<CommonBase>).Concat(item.Johns.Cast<CommonBase>).OrderBy(x => X.Order).ToList()
```